# Pass a vector to paste function in R

Tags: r, paste

I have a plot in my shiny app which I would like to make a title based on user selection.
Let say my `input$project` has 2 values `a` and `b`.

```
paste("Projects",input$project)

"Projects :  a" "Projects :  b"
```

My desired output is "

```
"Projects :  a,b"
```

Which apparently I can not get it via `paste` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
x <- letters[1:2]
paste("Projects: ", paste(x, collapse = ", "))

#> [1] "Projects:  a, b"
```

---

Or even shorter with `toString`, as suggested below by @ThomasIsCoding, to whom I thank:

```r
x <- letters[1:2]
paste("Projects: ", toString(x))

#> [1] "Projects:  a, b"
```

Comment: A shorter one is `toString(x)`

Comment: Thanks for having taught that to me, @ThomasIsCoding! Very useful!